# Firebase - How to create proxy for web app to prevent CORS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors

I have a React app that pulling data via Rest API from a different domain.

In my development env in order to work around this, I am using **http-proxy-middleware**.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware("/shabbat", {
        target: "https://www.hebcal.com",
        changeOrigin: true
    })
   )
 }
```

Since I am using Firebase to host my web app I need to handle this via Firebase but can't figure it our how to properly configure.

I would appreciate it if someone can share a working example.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i also got this error, i changed to use another https://xxx api to test,then worked well, so i guess this issue is due to firebase's settings, but i haven't found the solution